# Show that $e^x \geq (3/2) x^2$ for all non-negative $x$

Tags: calculus, inequality, taylor-expansion

I am attempting to solve a two-part problem, posed in Buck's *Advanced Calculus* on page 153. It asks "Show that $e^x \geq \frac{3}{2}x^2$  $\forall x\geq 0$. Can $3/2$ be replaced by a larger constant?"

This is after the section regarding Taylor polynomials, so I have been attempting to leverage the Taylor expansion for $e^x$ at $0$. $e^x \geq 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$, and by quadratic formula, we have $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}\geq \frac{3}{2}x^2$ for $x\in [0, \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}]$.

Now also $e^x\geq 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}$. We know there exists a $c\in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ such that for all $x\geq c$, we have $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}\geq \frac{3}{2}x^2$. I want to find this point without messing with the cubic formula, etc. I think I am missing a simpler way. Any ideas?

Comment: @Milind, thanks for the edit, for some reason I thought you could not use Latex in the title

Comment: A little bit of experimenting in Mathematica puts the constant at about $1.8475$.

Comment: The function $g(x)=e^{-x}x^2$ has derivative $(2-x)xe^{-x}$ and is maximum at $x=2$ on $[0,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider a quadratic $y=a x^2$ that is tangent to $y=e^x$. That is, we match function and derivative at a point $x=x_0$.  Then

$$e^{x_0}=a x_0^2$$
$$e^{x_0}=2 a x_0$$

Then $a x_0^2=2 a x_0$ so that $x_0=2$.  Plugging this back into one of the above equations, we get that

$$a=\frac{e^2}{4} \approx 1.84726$$

Consider, as @julien suggests, the function $g(x)=a x^2 e^{-x}$ which has derivative $a (2-x) x e^{-x}$ and second derivative $a (x^2-4 x+2) e^{-x}$.  This function represents the ratio of the quadratic to the exponential and is a maximum at $x=2$ for all $a>0$.  As $a x^2$ monotonically increases in $a$, we have

$$e^x \ge \frac{e^2}{4} x^2 \gt \frac{3}{2} x^2$$

Comment: I like this answer very much because it easily finds the sharpest possible limit. Thanks! @Julien, helpful clarification.

Answer (score 13):

Use AM-GM (i. e. $a+b \ge 2\sqrt{ab})$:

$$ x+x^3/6 \ge 2\sqrt{x^4/6}=x^2\sqrt{2/3}$$

$$1+x^4/24 \ge 2\sqrt{x^4/24}=x^2\sqrt{1/6}$$

Thus for all $x \ge 0$:

$$e^x \ge 1+x+x^2/2+x^3/6+x^4/24\ge x^2(1/2+ \sqrt{2/3}+\sqrt{1/6}) \ge 3/2 x^2$$

Comment: That's a beautiful method! Thanks

Comment: And the constant comes out $1.72474$ which is more than halfway from $1.5$ to the experimental value $1.8475$ noted by Ron Gordon in his comment to OP. +1

Answer (score 10):

Start from $e^x \geq 1 + x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $$e^x = e \cdot e^{x-1} \geq e \cdot x$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and  $$e^x = (e^{\tfrac{x}{2}})^2 \geq \left(\frac{e \cdot x}{2} \right)^2$$ for all $x \geq 0$.

Comment: That's elegant and yields the optimal bound without any analysis, just algebra. Now who knows why this is not the most upvoted answer...oh well, +1.

Comment: @julien: The optimality of this lower bound isn't clear, though.

Comment: @anonymous Try this inequality for $x=2$ to conclude that this factor is optimal.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x)=e^x/x^2$ and minimize on $(0, \infty)$, which means we first compute
$$f'(x)=\frac{(x-2)e^x}{x^3},$$
so the min occurs at $x=2$ and is $e^2/4$ in agreement  with Ron's answer, but doesn't involve making a curve tangent to $y=e^x$. (Note I only put up this answer for its direct "calc 1" appeal.)

Comment: This is an appealing way to go about it as well. I like that it uses the helpful strategy of minimizing f/g.